# Jade and Node.js store value from controller in hidden field

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, pug

I have this line in my jade file where i want to set the value #{target} but I get an error when it renders that this is illegal

```
input(type='hidden' name='target' value=#{target})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this should be:

```
// note the double qoutes around `#{}`
input(type="hidden" name="target" value="#{target}")
```

Comment: This won't work. The correct answer should be `value=target`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `#{}`. It should be `value=target`.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and you couldn't use interpolation, it worked like this for me:

```
input(type="hidden" name="upload" id="upload" value=upload._id)
```